# Fitlter concatted fields by list in Django ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I need to filter concat of two string values which is in a list:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

brands_to_search = ['Mercedes Benz', 'Opel Corsa']

result = models.VehicleModels.objects.filter(
    Concat('brand.manufacturer_description', ' ', 'model_description') # in brands_to_search
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

annotate function solved my problem.

```
from django.db.models import Value, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

result = models.VehicleModels.objects.annotate(
    brand_model=Concat(
        'brand__manufacturer_description',
        Value(' '),
        'model_description',
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).filter(brand_model__in=truck_models)
```